# How to directly send php to another page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to programming and am using html, mySQL and PHP to try and make a user name and password setup for user profiles. I then want to display a customized page to the user.

**The problem is, after I check to see if they are in the database, or not in the database, I can't figure out how to send them directly to a new page.**

I've tried using a function I found on google called `header()` but I keep getting an error.  I tried resolving it by making sure I had no output to the screen before using the `header()` function, and I'm pretty sure by now that I don't.  I don't actually know what the problem is and am trying to find another way to do this or just find an answer with `header()`. Anyhow, here's my code:

```
<?php

require "connect_to_mysql_and_test_connection.php";
//use the variable $db to access the database




?>
<html>
<head>
            <title>User Login</title>
            <h2>Login:</h2>
</head>
<body>
    <!--this makes a form to take the user input. the input of username and password. the submit buttons value is always submitted to $_POST-->
    <form method="post">
            Create user name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username" /><br>
            Create password:<br>
            <input type="text" name="password"/><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/><br>
    </form>
    <?php
            $compare_username="";
            $compare_password="";
            //get the username and password fields from the database and store it in a variable
            $username_password_fields=$db->query("SELECT username, password FROM users");//mysql object

            //get number of rows
            $rows= $username_password_fields->num_rows;

            //create a while loop to go through each row.
            while($rows >=1){
                            //iterate through each array returned by fetch_assoc to see if the username already exists
                            foreach($username_password_fields->fetch_assoc() as $key=>$value){
                                    //echo $key . $value . "<br>";
                                    //************check to see if the username exists****************
                                    if ($value === $_POST['username']){
                                            $compare_username=$value;
                                    }
                                    else  if ($value === $_POST['password']){
                                            $compare_password=$value;
                                    }


                            }
                            //check to see if the username matches the password
                            $rows -= 1;//decrement the rows remaining
                            if ($compare_username != "" and $compare_password != ""){

                                            //write code to send them to their custom page
                                            **header("Location:http://jasongriffore.atwebpages.com/myfirstworkingsite.php")<--This is the problem. please help!**
                                            echo "Ding ding ding a match!";
                                    return;
                            }
                            else if ($compare_username != ""){
                                    echo "This user name exists but the password is incorrect";
                                    //they can try again on the same page
                                    return;

                            }


            }

            //if after running the while loop they didn't get sent to their custom page, the must be new!

            echo "Let's create a new account for you!";
            //enter code to add a new user to the database 
    echo print_r($_POST, true);        
    ?>
```

Comment: *"I found on google called header() but I keep getting an error."* - Let me guess.... "Headers already sent".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` to buffer your output to the browser. You can read a little more about this [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php). The main reason you want to do this is because, the header tag requires that no output has been sent to the browser yet. By echoing out `<html><head>`... it's already sent data to the client, therefore no more headers can be sent (They are headers after all, intended to head the output.) `ob_start()` will buffer (Or store) everything until you're ready to output it, and will allow you later on to send headers because the output has not been sent to the browser yet.

```
<?php

require "connect_to_mysql_and_test_connection.php";
//use the variable $db to access the database

//Buffer the output
ob_start();



?>
<html>
<head>
            <title>User Login</title>
            <h2>Login:</h2>
</head>
<body>
    <!--this makes a form to take the user input. the input of username and password. the submit buttons value is always submitted to $_POST-->
    <form method="post">
            Create user name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="username" /><br>
            Create password:<br>
            <input type="text" name="password"/><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit"/><br>
    </form>
    <?php
            $compare_username="";
            $compare_password="";
            //get the username and password fields from the database and store it in a variable
            $username_password_fields=$db->query("SELECT username, password FROM users");//mysql object

            //get number of rows
            $rows= $username_password_fields->num_rows;

            //create a while loop to go through each row.
            while($rows >=1){
                            //iterate through each array returned by fetch_assoc to see if the username already exists
                            foreach($username_password_fields->fetch_assoc() as $key=>$value){
                                    //echo $key . $value . "<br>";
                                    //************check to see if the username exists****************
                                    if ($value === $_POST['username']){
                                            $compare_username=$value;
                                    }
                                    else  if ($value === $_POST['password']){
                                            $compare_password=$value;
                                    }


                            }
                            //check to see if the username matches the password
                            $rows -= 1;//decrement the rows remaining
                            if ($compare_username != "" and $compare_password != ""){

                                    //write code to send them to their custom page
                                    header("Location:http://jasongriffore.atwebpages.com/myfirstworkingsite.php");
                                    return;
                            }
                            else if ($compare_username != ""){
                                    echo "This user name exists but the password is incorrect";
                                    //they can try again on the same page
                                    return;

                            }


            }

            //if after running the while loop they didn't get sent to their custom page, the must be new!

            echo "Let's create a new account for you!";
            //enter code to add a new user to the database 
    echo print_r($_POST, true);      

    //Write the output to the browser
    ob_end_flush();  
    ?>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I run into this error with the code for ob_start() ob_end_flush() that you recommended.

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /srv/disk11/1807214/www/jasongriffore.atwebpages.com/index.php:2) in /srv/disk11/1807214/www/jasongriffore.atwebpages.com/index.php on line 54

Comment: Check to ensure you have no lines before that first opening <?php at the top.

Comment: Wow I can't believe that was the issue.  I had one blank line before <?php Thanks for the help. Your solution works as well :)

Comment: Sorry I'm new and had to figure out how hehe.

Comment: If you have some time: Add me on skype (danbopes). I have some suggestions for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php) function:

```
header('Location: mypage.php');
```

And be sure there is no output sent to the browser before you do so as I can see there is because your HTML `<form>` is **before** your PHP treatment. Change that.

Comment: I tried moving the <form> block of code to after the php but then my input boxes didn't show up? Thanks for the help btw :) People are nice on here.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript :

```
<script>window.location = 'http://jasongriffore.atwebpages.com/myfirstworkingsite.php';</script>
```

Comment: I haven't learned java script yet but your code worked! I don't know why, but thanks lol